# Iterating over the data received from ajax / json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, ajax

Below is the type of data I am getting via ajax.

```
[{"model": "blogapp.articles", "pk": 1, "fields": {"title": "Rainbow Buildings in Tokyo", "slug": "Rainbow-Buildings-in-Tokyo"}}, {"model": "blogapp.articles", "pk": 2, "fields": {"title": "4 Cool Cube Facades", "slug": "4-Cool-Cube-Facades"}}]
```

[image]

How can I iterate over this data using `.each` to get the title and the slug for each entry?

The below code gives me a syntax error on the data.

`app.js`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".tag-nav-links").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "",
      dataType: "json",
      data: { filter: `${e.target.textContent}` },
      success: function (data) {
        var html = "";
        $(data).each(function (index, value) {
          html += "<h4>{{" + value.title + "}}</h4>";
        });
        $("trial").append(html);
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `value.fields.title`?

Comment: You need to parse the string in `data.data` from json first , or fix the source so the array is not wrapped in quotes. `const arr = JSON.parse(data.data)`

Answer (score 0):

The [`jQuery` function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) (which you're using like this: `$(data)`) isn't what you want there. (You may have meant `$.each(data, ...)`, but these days there's no need.) If `data` really is an array as shown, just use `map` on it, then join the result together with a blank string:

```
success: function (data) {
    $("trial").append(data.map(value => {
        return "<h4>{{" + value.fields.title + "]]</h4>";
    }).join(""));
},
```

---

If `data` is really as shown in the screenshot, then it's an object with a `data` property containing a string of JSON. That's probably a misconfiguration or coding error on the server, current it's returning text something like this:

```json
{"data":"[{\"model\": \"blogapp.articles\", \"pk\": 1,...
```

when it should be returning something like this:

```json
{"data":[{"model":"blogapp.articles","pk":1,...
```

Something is pre-stringifying the data before passing it to whatever wraps it in the `{"data": ___}` wrapper, stringifies it, and returns it.

Until/unless you fix it, you'll have to parse it twice. jQuery is doing one of those for you, but you'll have to do the second one, after which you should be able to use the array:

```
// Until/unless the server is fixed
success: function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data.data); // *** Second parse
    $("trial").append(data.map(value => {
        return "<h4>{{" + value.fields.title + "]]</h4>";
    }).join(""));
},
```

If you fix the server so it's not double-stringifying, you'd use `data.data` instead (since `data` is your parameter name, and it refers to an object with a `data` property that has the array you want to use):

```
// After the server is fixed
success: function (data) {
    $("trial").append(data.data.map(value => {
    //                ^^^^^^^^^
        return "<h4>{{" + value.fields.title + "]]</h4>";
    }).join(""));
},
```

Comment: I tried this and am getting the error "TypeError: data.map is not a function".
Sorry I think the data I was receiving was an object not an array. I've added a picture of the object in the question. Can you help me iterate over this object to access title and slug?

Comment: @haashe - Looks like a server configuration/coding error, I've updated the answer to explain that a bit and give you an idea what to do both before and after fixing the server. Happy coding!